# How to add "addEventListener" to href?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add EventListener to href with id "logout"? I do not want to add all EventListener to add anchors at once.

```
<a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
    <img src="images/profile.png">
    <p>Edit Profile</p>
    <span>></span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
    <img src="images/setting.png">
     <p>Settings & Privacy</p>
     <span>></span>
</a>
<a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
     <img src="images/help.png">
     <p>Help & Support</p>
     <span>></span>
 </a>
 <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link" id="logout">
      <img src="images/logout.png">
      <p>Logout</p>
      <span>></span>
 </a>
```

Comment: you can't add a listener to an attribute

Comment: Then how can I add? Any other way? Do I need to change it to something else? I mean attribute is not important for me. If same functionality can be achieved by other element.

Comment: `document.getElementById('logout').addEventListener()` or `document.querySelector('#logout').addEventListener()` will work. To select an element with a specific href attribute you can also use `document.querySelector('[href="..."]')`

Comment: How are you adding your event listeners in the first place?

Comment: `document.querySelector("#logout")` / `document.getElementById("logout")` or even consider using [event delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) (which can still likely use `.querySelector()` or similar)

Comment: href is an attribute of anchor element. If you want to add event listener to anchor:    

`let logoutAnchor = document.getElementById("logout");
logoutAnchor.addEventListener("click", () => console.log("clicked!"))`

Comment: Also, if something is a button and not a link. Use a `<button>` element instead

Comment: @tacoshy This is not working, I do not know why? I think, it should work but may because it is an attribute that's why.

Comment: if you use a `<a>` link element, you use an automatic redirection to the link reference. This redirect has the final say on any event working code. Prefer to use a `<button>` element, this will be semantically more respectful

Comment: @WasimSafdar What are you doing and what exactly does not work? What do you expect the event listener to do? Please [edit] your question to include your attempt as a [mcve]

Comment: @Bergi. It is working now with event. It was not working before. Event without event. I do not know the reason because I was trying for more than half an hour.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To put in another way, if you want to add event listeners only to specific anchor tags without adding them all at once, then you can create a common ancestor element and do event-delegation.

```html
<div id="menuContainer">
  <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
    <img src="images/profile.png">
    <p>Edit Profile</p>
    <span>></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
    <img src="images/setting.png">
    <p>Settings & Privacy</p>
    <span>></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link">
    <img src="images/help.png">
    <p>Help & Support</p>
    <span>></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="sub-menu-link" id="logout">
    <img src="images/logout.png">
    <p>Logout</p>
    <span>></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

```js
let menuContainer = document.getElementById("menuContainer");

menuContainer.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target && event.target.matches("a#logout") {
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log("Logout element clicked!");
    }
});
```

This way, you only need to attach one event listener which is to the common ancestor element, even if you add more anchor tags in the future.

Comment: There is only a single element with id `logout`, why would you need event delegation for this?

Comment: @Bergi The OP question is a bit tricky and I know there is only one `logout` that needs attention.

I'm saying particularly about this piece in the question - `I do not want to add all EventListener to add anchors at once.`

I have written this answer in terms of the above statement by rephrasing what I can understand from it before writing the solution if you check clearly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add like so.

```
<a href="#" id="logout">Click me</a>
<script>
  // Get the anchor element by its ID
  var myLink = document.getElementById('logout');
  // Add a click event listener
  myLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    // Your code here
    alert('Link clicked!');
    // Prevent the default behavior (in this case, following the link)
    event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Select the element you want to add event;

```js
let myElement = document.querySelector('#logout');
```

- Add event;

```js
myElement.addEventListener('click', function() => {
    alert('Link clicked!');
    //Since it' s an anchor, prevent the default behaviour 
    event.preventDefault();
})
```